# Access to front ceiling light box on a 2006 Acura TSX

Tags: acura, power

I'm trying to follow these instructions for my similar TSX:

http://tl.acurazine.com/forums/showthread.php?t=540405

But I haven't found the proper way to remove the front ceiling light cover (the one with the garage door opener, sunroof power, lights, rearview mirror power, etc).  I think it doesn't involve any screws, just a thin shim in the right spot.

Can you help me get it off without scratching, breaking, or unnecessary steps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, you need to put a flat head screw driver near the back edge of the lens and gently pry it off. Then you should be able to pull the lens out of the housing to remove it.

This video might help:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRPv4aVg9b8

Comment: While this video is relevant, your answer should really also stand on its own.  Could you summarize some of the key points of the video for the asker?